# Fetching and returning JSON files via AJAX, Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

im just trying to post some open data information from a website onto an AJAX form using JS and HTML. But i cannot get it to work for the life of me...the open data source im using is from https://data.winnipeg.ca/City-Planning/Plow-Zone-Schedule/tix9-r5tc

My HTML form is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>AJAX Assignment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"> 
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">Winnipeg's Plow Schedule</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Search the history of the City of Winnipeg's Snow Plow schedule'.</h2>
      <form class="box" id="searchform"> 
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Search for Plow Zone by Zone Letter</label>
      </div>
      <div class="field has-addons"> 
        <div class="control is-expanded"> 
          <input class="input is-full-width" name="common-name" id="common-name"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="control"> 
          <button class="button is-primary" type="submit" id="submit">Search</button> 
        </div> 
      </div>
      </form><br>
      <h2 class="explanation subtitle"></h2> <br> 
      <div id = "div1">
        <table class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable trees">
          <thead></thead> 
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table> 
      </div>
      <br>  
         
     <p> Plow data provided by the <a href="https://data.winnipeg.ca/">City of Winnipeg Open Data catalogue</a>. </p> 
   </div>       
      </div> 
    </body>

</html>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
    function fetch(){

    let commonName = document.getElementById("common-name").value.toLowerCase(); 
    const apiUrl = 'https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/tix9-r5tc.json' +
                `$where=common_name LIKE '%${commonName}%'` +
                '&$order=shift_start DESC' +
                '&$limit=100';
    const encodedURL = encodeURI(apiUrl);

    fetch(encodedURL)
    .then(function(result) {
      return result.json(); // Promise for parsed JSON.
    })
    .then(function(data) {

        let body = document.getElementByTagName("tbody")[0];
      
        let headingRows = document.createElement("tr");
        body.appendChild(headingRows);

        let nameHead = document.createElement("th");
        nameHead.innerHTML = 'Zone';
        headingRows.appendChild(nameHead);

        let startHead = document.createElement("th");
        startHead.innerHTML = 'Shift Start';
        headingRows.appendChild(startHead);

        let endHead = document.createElement("th");
        endHead.innerHTML = 'Shift End';
        headingRows.appendChild(endHead);

        for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
            let createRows = document.createElement("tr");
            body.appendChild(createRows);

            let createName = document.createElement("td");
            createName.innerHTML = data[i].plow_zone;
            createRows.appendChild(createName);

            let createStart = document.createElement("td");
            createStart.innerHTML = data[i].shift_start;
            createRows.appendChild(createStart);

            let createEnd = document.createElement("td");
            createEnd.innerHTML = data[i].shift_end;
            createRows.appendChild(createEnd);
       } 

    });
  }

  function load(){
   document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", 
    function(){fetch()});
  }
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);
```

when I attempt to run the page and search for the Plow Zone? I simply get:
[image: pic1]

if anyone can see where im going wrong? i would greatly appreciate that. It seems like my event listener for my button isnt calling my fetch function or something...either that or it IS working...but something is not correct with my JS.

Comment: You've named your click handler `fetch` which will overwrite the built-in `fetch`, hence the recursion. Name it something else (`fetchData` for example). Also, your form will be submitting normally. I'd suggest using `type="button"` on your button to prevent it doing so.

Comment: You're calling `fetch()` inside of itself, as in inside of function `function fetch(){`, which will then itself call `fetch()`, which will then itself call `fetch()`, which will then itself call `fetch()`, which will then its...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is called `function fetch(){` within this function you call `fetch(encodedURL)` this will create a infinite recursion. Give your outer function another name and the error will be gone.